# Pass GET value to UploadHandler in BlueImp JQuery file Upload Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, blueimp

I've got the upload script working on a PHP server. What I am trying to do is pass a value to the script so that I can get the images to upload to a particular directory rather than the default /files/ direction

I've added the following to the php folder index.php

```
$options = array('upload_dir'=>$upload_dir, 'upload_url'=>$upload_url); 
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
```

and now I want to define the upload_dir and upload_url with something like:

```
$upload_dir = '/var/www/vhosts/bla/bla2/incident/image-upload/server/php/'. $_GET['id'] . '/';
```

but no matter what I try, I cannot pass the variable to this page from the rest of the code.

Can someone please shed some light on how to do this?

I'd like the variable to be passed when the page loads rather than after the form is submitted so the images from the specific folder with a name of the GET value are available to the page when it loads.

Thanks!

Comment: `submit` callback is what you looking for

Comment: Could you possibly be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: Just go to the plugin repo and read the wiki